# Do I need to pass className prop to extend a component's style?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I created a Card component that I want to modify by extending it.
But in order to do that, I need to pass a prop called `className` like the code bellow.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { CardStyle } from './style';
import { CardInterface } from './interface';

const Card = (props: CardInterface) => {
  const { children, className } = props;

  return (
    <CardStyle className={className}>
      {children}
    </CardStyle>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

My question is, There's no other way where I don't need to pass the `className` prop to my component in order to extend it?

The piece of code where I try to extend the `Card`.

```js
export const CardWithTabs = styled(Card)`
  border-radius: 0px;
`;
```

Comment: You can have a default value variable for className and set it's value from prop only when available.

Comment: Are there any issues you are facing with passing the `className` prop?

Comment: Actually, there's no issue at all but I thought that I didn't need to do that in order to extend a component

Comment: I'd assume `CardInterface` expects `className`? Therefore if you extend `Card` to `CardWithTabs`, `CardWithTabs` will also expect `className` as it inherited `CardInterface`.

Can you also post the TS `Interface` code?

Answer (score 0):

I expect `import { CardInterface } from './interface';` looks like this:

```
export interface CardInterface {
  className: string;
}
```

So if `const Card = (props: CardInterface)`, when you extend `CardWithTabs = styled(Card)`, `CardWithTabs` will inherit `CardInterface` and also require `className`.

```
<CardWithTabs className="bleh" />
```

To have `className` not required you can make `className` optional in your `interface` with a `?`:

```
export interface CardInterface {
  className?: string;
}
```

Or, when extending `Card`, drop the `className` prop from being passed on:

```
// You will need to add an interface for CardComponent of course
const CardComponent = ({
  children,
  className,
  ...rest
}) => <Card {...rest}>{children}</Card>;

const CardWithTabs = styled(CardComponent)`
  /* Your styles */
`;
```

This answer is base on assumptions from the code supplied.